# Row Cumulative in a dataframe considering the Dates - R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, cumulative-sum

I have a data frame, which each row contains the points for each user that are obtained in certain dates (dates are presented in the last row).

**Example:**

```
         X1         X2          X3          X4          X5          X6
user1   123         0           324         8734        435         86
user2   34          63          65          35          566         92  
user3   45          54          8764        0           8976        874     
user4   0           21          7653        974         4235        324 
user5   5           647         842         2345        29          7652
Dates   2010-03-12  2010-03-12  2010-03-13  2010-03-14  2010-03-14  2010-03-14
```

I want to accumulate the values for each row that belong to a date.
Example (having the above table):

```
        X1          X2          X3
user1   123         447         9702
user2   97          162         855     
user3   99          8863        18713
user4   21          7674        13207
user5   652         1494        11520
Dates   2010-03-12  2010-03-13  2010-03-14
```

I could do it using a `for` loop but I know it is not an efficient solution. So, I am looking for an efficient way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider the transpose of the data and then use `group_by` + `sum`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @yarnabrina we could transpose convert `factor`/`character` columns to `numeric` `group_by` `Dates` and `sum` and finally transpose it again.

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(t(df)) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("user")), ~as.numeric(as.character(.))) %>%
   group_by(Dates) %>%
   summarise_all(sum) %>%
   ungroup() %>% t %>% data.frame()

#              X1         X2         X3
#Dates 2010-03-12 2010-03-13 2010-03-14
#user1        123        324       9255
#user2         97         65        693
#user3         99       8764       9850
#user4         21       7653       5533
#user5        652        842      10026
```

---

Or another approach using base R is to `split` the columns based on last row, convert them to numeric and take row-wise sum.

```
sapply(split.default(df[-nrow(df), ], unlist(df[nrow(df), ])), 
         function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, as.numeric);rowSums(x)})

#      2010-03-12 2010-03-13 2010-03-14
#user1        123        324       9255
#user2         97         65        693
#user3         99       8764       9850
#user4         21       7653       5533
#user5        652        842      10026
```